# replace() takes no keyword arguments, in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, typeerror, keyword-argument

I'm trying to convert multiple columns of dollar amount into float, and wrote the following code

```
    for column in wo.columns[14:21]:
        column = (column.replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True )
                   .replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).replace('#NAME?','NaN', regex=True).astype(float))
    return column


And this is the error i get:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-276-f7c13cb3d0af> in <module>
      1 for column in wo.columns[14:19]:
----> 2     column = (column.replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True )
      3                .replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).replace('#NAME?','NaN', regex=True).astype(float))
      4 return column
      5 

TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

What might be wrong? 
wo is the name of the dataframe, the library i used to load the dataframe was Pandas, and when i used the code on other individual columns it worked fine, just when i used a for loop it return an error.

Comment: If you use an external library add it to the tags of the question. And show definition of "wo".

Comment: If you use pandas, you need to apply the replace to the `str` of the DataFrame or Series like so: `column.str.replace`. The `str` part has to be added every time before the `replace` function.

Comment: Also, pandas regex=True is the default and does not need to be specified.

Answer (score 7):

It is giving an error because it doesn't accept keyword arguments; in this case `regex=True`.  As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), it doesn't exist.  Also, `.replace` is for strings only, so the type of data here should be `str`.  On the other hand, should you want to use regex, I'd recommend `re.sub`

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the 'regex = True' will be helpful from my case.

```
# df_num_key_split[name][var].replace(to_replace="[\[|\]|']|\s+|\.|\-", value='', regex=True)
```

After I did this, it worked.

```
df_num_key_split[name][var].replace("[\[|\]|']|\s+|\.|\-", '')
```

Answer (score 1):

What type is column? 
`print(type(column))`
if its a str, it is going to use
str.replace, which takes no kwargs. Try deleting `regex=True`.